# Is there a more efficient way to do this

Tags: php, mysql

```
function countBrand($brand_id, $brand_name) {
    $sql = "SELECT brand FROM coupons WHERE expire >= CURRENT_DATE AND brand='".$brand_id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<li>'.$brand_name.'</li>';
}

function brandCount() {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT brand,brand_id,brand_name FROM coupons,coupons_brand WHERE brand=brand_id AND expire >= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY brand_name";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo '<h3>'.$num.' Brands</h3>';

    echo '<ul>';

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) {
        $brand_id = mysql_result($result, $i, "brand_id");
        $brand_name = mysql_result($result, $i, "brand_name");
        countBrand($brand_id, $brand_name);
        $i++;
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

It works perfectly and gives me the results I am looking for. I am not as strong with sql statements as I would like to be. Is there a way I could do this that would be more efficient, it seems very slow.

Basically, it counts how many brands have coupons, then coupons how many coupons each brand has..

I also, on the same page, do this for categories. There are a few thousand categories and maybe 20,000 coupons.

Comment: Don't nest function definitions like this. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Can you be more clear so I can understand [I understand the nesting functions but it works and does what I want, not sure what would be wrong.].?

Comment: Functions, regardless of where they're defined, exist at the global scope. Calling the outer function a second time will crash the PHP script due to the inner function being declared a second time.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. The inner function for cats and brands are different and only called once [in this particular mess].

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the current code - given Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams correction.

Comment: Can u provide the table layouts? That is probably the easiest way to find out a solution - the php code is irrelevant to a certain degree.

Comment: Ideally, questions like this should give an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish -- narrow what you're asking down to exactly one simple question. Explain your goals and assumptions, and show what you've reasoned through and what you've determined. Don't just dump a bunch of code and say "how can I make this better". Code is important, but it's not the question, it's a supporting exhibit. Code is necessarily more difficult for humans to interpret than prose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few php optimisations you could do, but they probably wont save you much time, compared to adding an index to mysql on the correct columns

i have commented some php optimisations below, maybe of interest to you anyway

given the simple nature of the functions, it is not necessary to have 2 functions, and that would save the timecost of calling countBrand(), (although it is a pretty minimal time saving)

```
   function countBrand($brand_id, $brand_name) {
        $sql = "SELECT brand FROM coupons WHERE expire >= CURRENT_DATE AND brand='".$brand_id."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) || die (mysql_error()); // always check for errors

        list($brand) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// fetch row, returns a more concise array then mysql_fetch_array
//        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        // use commas rather then . when concatenating echo statements
        // dots force concatenation before output
        echo '<li>',$brand,'</li>'; 

    }

    function brandCount() {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT brand,brand_id,brand_name FROM coupons,coupons_brand WHERE brand=brand_id AND expire >= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY brand_name";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error()); // always check for errors

    //    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // not sure why this is needed
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result); 

        // use commas rather then . when concatenating echo statements
        // dots force concatenation before output
        echo '<h3>',$num,' Brands</h3>';

        echo '<ul>';

      // fetch all cols at once, rather then using lots of separate calls to mysql_result
      // use mysql_fetch_row as it returns just the ordered values (vs mysql_fetch_assoc, and mysql_fetch_array)
      // 
       while(list($brand, $brand_id, $brand_name) == mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            countBrand($brand_id, $brand_name);
       }

      // replaced with while loop above
      //  $i = 0;
      //  while ($i < $num) {
      //      $brand_id = mysql_result($result, $i, "brand_id");
      //      $brand_name = mysql_result($result, $i, "brand_name");
     //       countBrand($brand_id, $brand_name);
      //      $i++;
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

those enhancements will only give you a minor speed increase
the biggest speed increase you will get is if you call the database less.

currently you select each brand, and then go back and count each brand individually
without knowing the structure of you tables this sql is difficult for me to write, so it is a guess, but it should point you in the right direction

```
SELECT brand, brand_id, brand_name, COUNT(*) as brandcount
FROM coupons
JOIN coupons_brand ON brand=brand_id 
WHERE expire >= CURRENT_DATE 
GROUP BY brand, brand_id, brand_name
ORDER BY brand_name
```

Comment: WOW, bumperbox... Just WOW. With the info you provided [WOW] I am able to do everything needed, A LOT faster. I cannot begin to thank you enough for your time and consideration. Amazing answer... I thank you, thank you, thank you....

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array($result,**MYSQL_ASSOC**);

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE brand FROM
```

[Profiling query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Userpassword.